# Job Tracker in Hadoop 2

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop2

I am using Hadoop 2 (i.e) CDH 5.4.5 which is based on Hadoop 2.6 which is YARN.

Still if i see mapred-site.xml, there is property defined **

> mapred.job.tracker

**
which in Hadoop 2 should not be there. What can be the reason for this..?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's deprecated doesn't mean it shouldn't be there. Backwards compatible-ness isn't a bad thing.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html

Comment: But why property is needed as the compatibility is handled in the code by using the specific classes and as it is written that in Hadoop 2 there is no jobtracker & tasktracker then which service runs on port 8021 which they mention in mapred-site.xml

Comment: Who said it was needed? Try deleting, see what breaks. That property isn't defined in the current mapred-default.xml, so maybe Cloudera just left it in there mistakenly

Comment: Please check i am using cloudera quick start vm 4.7
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<configuration><property><name>mapred.job.tracker</name><value>localhost.localdomain:8021</value></property><property><name>mapred.job.tracker.http.address</name><value>0.0.0.0:50030</value></property><property><name>mapreduce.job.counters.max</name><value>120</value></property><property><name>mapred.output.compress</name><value>false</value></property><property><name>mapred.output.compression.type</name>

Comment: The same thing i found out in cloudera quickstart vm 5.4

Comment: I don't want or have the means to start the quickstart vm. I'm telling you if you are sure you are running Hadoop 2,then that property is not used.

Comment: The problem is that property is also used by other tools like kite-dataset, t if mapped.job.tracker is there a `kite-dataset csv-import movies.csv movies' will fail with a connection error to 'localhost:8021' (job tracker). If that property is removed from `/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml` then it won't try to use the JobTracker